# SQS invoke multiple lambda at same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am new in aws sqs as of now I understand sqs have a queue which is storing request messages (parameter) then our attached lambda will fetch numbers of messages based on the batch file which we set on lambda.

so if the sqs queue has 10000 messages and the lambda batch is set to 100 then in each pulling lambda which fetches 100 messages from the queue and executes all until all request are processed then again it will pull 100 messages and so on?

so as of now, I understand lambda will wait for the next pulling until the previous pulling process is finished.

hope I am correct if not please correct me.

now my requirement is lambda should not wait to finish the previous pulling instead it should pull the next 100 messages and execute parallelly for eg lambda should create a different instance(something like this) and each instance pulls 100 100 messages and execute parallelly.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, the AWS Lambda service will **automatically run multiple AWS Lambda functions** based upon the concurrency settings of your function.

See: [Lambda function scaling - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

The default is to permit **up to 1000 concurrent executions** of an AWS Lambda function.

Therefore, **you do not need to change anything**. It will automatically create multiple instances of the Lambda function in parallel and pass (up to) 100 messages to each execution.

For a really good series of articles to understand how AWS Lambda operates, see: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)